# Best way to add dragable images onto another image in android

Tags: android

I was wondering what the best way to add dragable images to another image is in android. For example if I had an image of someones face how could I add an smaller image of say a comedy mouth and drag it into the correct position on the original image. Is there a nice way to go about this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site is not for doing your programming. Find the programming constructs that you might need to solve your problem, and come back if you have a specific problem with any of them.

Comment: The best way to overlap images in your app is using FrameLayout.Please check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FrameLayout to overlap your images.Check this out:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <ImageView 
      android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:src="@drawable/img_face"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"
      android:layout_height="250px"
      android:layout_width="250px"/>

   <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/imageView2"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:src="@drawable/comedy_face"
      android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Would this work for multiple new images though? Say glasses and a mouth could be added to the original image.

Comment: Yes in FrameLayout you can add as many images you want.Please try it once,if it doesn't work please post your code so that we can help you out.@JVDM